# How to create a simple WYSIWYG text editor without contentEditable or designMode?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I would like to create a very simple WYSIWYG text editor that would only allow the user to italicize or bold the text.
I was using a simple `div` with `contentEditable` but users could paste formatted text or format text using their browser features.
What I want is more like a `textarea` with bold or italic text inside…
I heard about a technique of hidden `textarea` but I didn't really understood how it works (how the user can change the cursor position…)

Comment: You could use http://ckeditor.com/ and disable the features you don't want in it

Comment: I have no idea how to disable pasting of formatted text: CKeditor uses contentEditable...

Comment: If you disable all other features than Bold and Italic, the CKEditor won't allow to paste anything else. See the difference in pasting into those 3 editors: http://ckeditor.com/demo#toolbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im putting this as a more formal answer

---

You can basically use ckeditor [here](http://ckeditor.com) and as Renmar suggested, you can disable buttons which disable formatting features. e.g:

- Disabling Bold and Italic will remove any bold and Italic formatting on preformated text

You can experiment [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo#toolbar) in the text editors where some features have been disabled